# Rate limit the API method sendverificationcode in Identity Platform

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-identity-toolkit

Is there a way to rate limit a certain method for the Identity toolkit API. I want to limit the following API, as I am incurring heavy usage costs from OTP requests.

POST identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:sendverificationcode

Thank you for the help.

Comment: You can try using this link to manage your quotas and limits: [https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/quota-management](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/quota-management). Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to **[Manage quotas and limits](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/quota-management)** documentation in order to create a rate limit in the Identity Platform Console.

From the documentation:

> 1. In the Google Cloud Console, go to the `APIs & Services` page.
> 2. Select the API you want to monitor quotas for. For your case, `Identity Toolkit API`.
> 3. Click `Quotas`.
> 4. Select the operation you want to edit, then click `Edit quotas`. You can select multiple operations to edit at a time.
> 5. Enter a number within the limits set for the operation.
> 6. Click `Submit request` to update the operation's quota.

Additional Reference:
[Method: accounts.sendVerificationCode](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/reference/rest/v1/accounts/sendVerificationCode)